# What is the name for the glove worn to take out baked food from oven, so that touching the hot tray doesn't burn our hands?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, transatlantic-differences

Is there a specific name for the thick glove worn (or may be any cloth used) to touch hot dishes in the oven?

For example, we wear a glove and take the dish containing baked food from the oven.

It's use is to save our hand from being burnt by touching the hot dish.

Comment: Which country do you live in?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I live in Pakistan. Why do you ask?

Comment: The common name for this varies from country to country, that's all.  Some people (eg UK) call it an oven glove, some (eg USA, Australia) an oven mitt.  When using english phrases, does Pakistan tend to favour american or british english?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, Having done some research for a localised app, I found that Pakistan is closer to British English since it was once under the rule of the British Raj. However, since Pakistani English is a dialect in it's own right, there may have been an answer specific to the dialect.

Comment: @MaxWilliams We were taught British English in school which was a few years ago. These days, I, as well  as most of the people around me, are more inclined towards American English.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: It wouldn't be so hot if they used an `~`!

Comment: Williams Sonoma has a page for "Oven Mitts, Oven Gloves and Cooking Mitts" to cover all the bases.

Comment: Some people call these a "Round Tuit" (like a potholder of a circular shape.) If you have a friend who seems to not get around to doing things, you can give him one. It gets rid of the excuse: "I'll do it when I get a Round Tuit." (Warning: US droll humor)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to identify the object the OP is describing, I  posted this answer with the term I use. At first I didn't think about alternative expressions based on geographical location. Other users did that after mine. I think the OP  can enjoy a  lively and useful discussion on the theme.

***[Oven glove](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oven-glove)***:

> <sub><sup>BRITISH ENGLISH</sup></sub> - a ​thick ​covering for the ​hand, used for taking ​hot things out of an ​oven

(Cambridge Dictionary)

[image]

Answer (score 133):

We call them ***[Oven Mitts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oven_glove)***.

At least online shopping seems to confirm!

It's interesting to see that '***oven glove***' is used too, it's obvious, but around here (NZ and Australia, and apparently the States) they are 'mitts'.

However, looking up the definition of ***[mitt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mitt)***:

> a glove leaving the fingers and thumb-tip exposed.

Well, that's the last thing you want isn't it!

Regardless, that is what we call them :)

Comment: But "mitt" is short for "mitten", and the sense of "mitt" as a fingerless glove is only used in sports.

Comment: Fair enough...  I only went to the Oxford - ha, if that sounds sarcastic (?) it wasn't meant to be!

Comment: Oven mitt is certainly what I am most familiar with, in the US.

Comment: I've also heard "hot mitt" in the US (Midwest/South).

Comment: The first definition in your link is "a mitten".  Which is defined as "A glove with two sections, one for the thumb and the other for all four fingers."  Exactly what we're looking for.

Comment: From Texas...  Oven Mitt all my life.  I've never heard Oven Glove.

Comment: "A glove leaving the fingers and thumb-tip exposed" is only one of the definitions given at your link, and clearly not the one meant here.

Comment: In Canada, too, this is an oven mitt. And here in the Great White North, a mitt(en) is first and foremost a glove with only two sections, usually worn to keep one's hands warm in winter. This extension to the oven is natural. The sporting sense of the word is a distant third. (Before this question, I had never heard of an oven glove.)

Comment: I have an actual oven glove; it looks like an ordinary knitted glove but is made from Nomex (what they use in racing safety garments).  It makes it much easier to manipulate hot items, but it's harder to get on and off than an oven mitt.

Comment: Leather gloves going up the arm used in working with extremely high heats, such as forges, foundries, kilns, etc. are called simply 'mitts' -- I had thought this was the origin of a (cooking) 'oven mitt', with the advent of modern kitchen ovens. But now I'm not sure, and could find no evidence on the internet.

Comment: @HotLicks - Depends on the sport, of course.  In baseball, the catcher's mitt does not generally have exposed fingers.  Then again, neither do fielders' gloves.  I think the difference is in purpose.  I think of a mitt as generally more for protection (e.g. from the oven's heat or a 90mph fastball), whereas a glove may serve other purposes.

Comment: @user1359 FWIW, my almost forearm length TIG welding gloves are *gloves* (in NZ). They have individual fingers.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure that 'mitten' isn't a diminutive of 'mitt"', used to denote diminished mitts, i.e. without complete fingers. I'm Australain and I've never heard 'oven glove' in my long life.

Comment: @EJP - Virtually every US child who is taken outside in the wintertime is equipped with "mittens" to keep his hands warm.  This has been true since 1955 or so that I can personally vouch for, and I'm relatively sure I've read of it in stories going back to 1910 at least.  In the US "mitt", in addition to being a (rarely used) diminutive of "mitten", is used for gloves worn by baseball players and players in a few other sports.  Often these sports "mitts" leave the back of the hand and fingers exposed (presumably so that the hands do not get too warm, and to reduce the weight of the mitt).

Answer (score 26):

While oven mitts work, my family usually used rectangular pieces of cloth that were often also purposed as placemats to stop the tablecloth from melting/catching on fire.  These are called [***Pot holders***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pot%20holder), though the single word "potholders" is also used on shopping sites.

[image]

They also come in silicone!

Comment: These are sometimes also designed to (and any can in principle) serve double duty as a trivet [the object you put _under_ a hot pan to protect the table from the heat] - EDIT: I see you've mentioned this but using the term 'placemat'. Cloth pot holders also sometimes have a pocket to slip your fingers into, making it a sort of half oven mitt.

Comment: I have encountered devoted trivets, particularly metal (or non-cloth) ones, so rarely I didn't even know the word.  Neat!

Comment: Many silicone ones seem to be designed as trivets first, having a shape and texture (e.g. hexagonal or round with honeycomb cells) that makes them somewhat awkward to use as potholders.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Oven Mitts, Oven Glove and Pot Holders, I often hear them referred to as **Hot Mitts**.

[image: Hot Mitts]

Comment: http://www.kitchenkapers.com/7645.html

Comment: After a little research, the term seems to describe flameproof cooking gloves/mitts. Hence the name of this particular article is  *Flameguard".