# What is this called: British oven pot holders connected by towel

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, nouns, terminology

I'm a Yank, and I often see on British TV a pot holder or oven mitt like this: two square mitts (terry cloth?) connected by a dish towel or tea towel, so it's all one piece. What are they called?

The ones I've seen, on Great British Baking Show for instance, are not gloves. They are two square pot holders that you slip your hands inside, connected with by an additional piece of cloth. Maybe the cloth helps prevent burning your forearms on the pan?

I cannot find out what this is called, and we just don't seem to have them in the USA. I'd really like to know where to get some.

Comment: Do you mean *oven gloves*?

Comment: Colloquially we call them 'oven gloves', commercially they seem to be called 'double oven gloves', to differentiate them from oven mits which we also call oven gloves, but we would call two oven mitts a 'pair of oven gloves'. I'm sure I've made that perfectly clear...

Comment: The ones I've seen, on Great British Baking Show for instance, are not gloves. They are two square pot holders that you slip your hands inside, connected with by an additional piece of cloth. Maybe the cloth helps prevent burning your forearms on the pan? I'd really like to know where to get some...

Comment: @Bridget - they're not gloves in the strict sense of the word, but the objects you're looking for are definitely called 'oven gloves' in the UK. As to where you can buy them, any UK kitchen-ware shop will have them. I don't know where you live, so don't know whether the online shops will deliver to your location, but Lakeland is a very popular supplier of such things, and they deliver to the whole of Europe.

Comment: Picture please!

Comment: @Mitch: Look at the answer below...

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking I have no idea if that's what the OP is looking for. The OP's words don't match in my mind what the 'double oven mitt' looks like.

Comment: I can see two reasons for linking them up like that: you can drape them over a towel rack when they are not in use; and you can't lose one of them. I'm surprised you don't have them over there!

Comment: Related: [What is the name for the glove worn to take out baked food from oven, so that touching the hot tray doesn't burn our hands?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277168/what-is-the-name-for-the-glove-worn-to-take-out-baked-food-from-oven-so-that-to)

Answer (score 3):

To simply answer your questions, here in the UK they are simply referred to as oven gloves but I feel that is more of a general term for cloth designed to be used to hold hot pots.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are just called double oven mitts. See photo here: https://food52.com/shop/products/82-double-oven-mitt

Answer (score 0):

They are called oven gloves: .

https://www.lakeland.co.uk/in-the-kitchen/baking/oven-gloves%2C-tea-towels-and-aprons/oven-gloves-and-mitts/